# ASP.NET Framework MVC send Razor View data with ajax to the server after validation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am doing an ASP.NET Framework MVC project and I need to send the combo boxes selected items from below partial view to the server with **Jquery Ajax** but these combo boxes must be validated at first and then the data must be sent in **view model** with **Ajax** to the action (DigestFile(ModelDto Mappings)) in the controller. My project parts is as below :

The partial view as below:

```
    @using Web.Library.Bases;
    @inherits  Common.DataTransferObjects.Originals.ModelDto
    @{
        Layout = "";
        List<(string Caption, bool IsAsigned, bool IsMandatory, bool IsSelected, string Name, string Title)> dataBaseFields = ViewBag.DataBaseFields;
        int counter = 0;
     }
    <div id="Excel_B" class="editor-block">
        @Html.Hidden("IsNotMatched")
        <div class="block-label">
            <p class="vertical-text">
                تناظر فیلدها
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            @foreach (var chlItem in dataBaseFields)
            {
                <div id="ExcelFields_G" class="editor-group ">
                    <div id="ExcelFields_L" class="editor-label mandatory">
                        <span class="MappingLabel">@chlItem.Caption :</span>
                    </div>
                    @switch (chlItem.Name)
                    {
                        case "RowNumber":
                            <div id="ExcelFields_A" class="editor-field ">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RowNumber, "ComboBox")
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RowNumber)
                            </div>
                            break;
                        case "Name":
                            <div id="ExcelFields_B" class="editor-field ">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, "ComboBox")
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                            </div>
                            break;
                        case "Family":
                            <div id="ExcelFields_C" class="editor-field ">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Family, "ComboBox")
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Family)
                            </div>
                            break;
                        case "Code":
                            <div id="ExcelFields_D" class="editor-field ">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code, "ComboBox")
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
                            </div>
                            break;
                        case "NationalCode":
                            <div id="ExcelFields_E" class="editor-field ">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NationalCode, "ComboBox")
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NationalCode)
                            </div>
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
            }
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    @if (Model.IsNotMatched > 0)
        {
            <div class="DigestBut" title="Read File">
                <a href="#" class="submitLink" onclick="DigestButtonClicked()">
                    Read File
                </a>
            </div>
        }
</div>
</div>
```

The View Model as below:

```
namespace Common.DataTransferObjects.Originals
{
    public class ModelDto
    {
        [Display(Name = "RowNumber")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(FoundationValidationMessages))]
        public string RowNumber { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(FoundationValidationMessages))]
        public string Name { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "Family")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(FoundationValidationMessages))]
        public string Family { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "Code")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(FoundationValidationMessages))]
        public string Code { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "NationalCode")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(FoundationValidationMessages))]
        public string NationalCode { set; get; }
    }
}
```

The Action is as below:

```
public ActionResult DigestFile(ModelDto Mappings)
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: I am little confused do you mean by  "combo boxes" the Edit field ?

Comment: Hello. The "ComboBox" in  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NationalCode, "ComboBox") is a helper attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you have to proceed in case you have many 'entries' to send in same time to save in your controller, but of course you can use it to send only one:

In your view:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="SaveMe()" />
<script>
function SaveMe() {

    // Get the value of your edit

    var RowNumber0 = $("#RowNumber").val();
    var Name0 = $("#Name").val();
    var Family0 = $("#Family").val();
    var Code0= $("#Code").val();
    var NationalCode0= $("#NationalCode").val();


    // Creat Object

    var lineItems = new Object();
    lineItems.Entrys = new Array();

    // Example Filling your object...

    lineItems.Entrys[0] = new Object({ RowNumber: RowNumber0, Name: Name0, Family: Family0, Code : Code0, NationalCode: NationalCode0 });

    //lineItems.Entrys[1] = ... same logic for your other entries


    // send by ajax to your controller and getting answer ...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/AjaxMethodDigestFile",
        data: JSON.stringify({ Entrys: lineItems.Entrys }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) { alert(response.message); },
        failure: function (response) { alert("failure"); },
        error: function (response) { alert("error"); }
    });
}
```

in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxMethodDigestFile(ICollection<Common.DataTransferObjects.Originals.ModelDto > Entrys)
{
string message = "";
int counter = 0;

foreach (var entry in Entrys)
{
    // How to use this data example
    string RowNumber = entry.RowNumber;
    string Name= entry.Name;
    counter += 1;
    message += "Saved " + ": " + counter + Constants.vbCrLf;
}

// The following lines are not necessary, it's just an example code to know what happen and return it to client side ...
if (counter > 0)
    message = counter.ToString() + " Entrys received" + Constants.vbCrLf + message;
else
    message = "no entrys";


var response = new { counter, message };

return Json(response);
```

}

**EDIT:**
*About the validation*

I don't know the library that you are using `FoundationValidationMessages` so can't help much with this, but I tried a classic way that work:

In Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public string RowNumber { set; get; }
```

In View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test2", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
...
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RowNumber)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RowNumber)
...
}
```

And in your controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test2(ModelDto um)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(um);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, That was great and now I can send view data in format of view model with ajax to the server but I have another problem that is I must validate these comboboxes  by clicking the button "Read File".(You know That ComboBox in @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RowNumber, "ComboBox") is a helper attribute, that I made an helper view in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder). You see that I have @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RowNumber) but it does not work. Whould you please help me?

Comment: Nice to hear that jQuery problem solved, I edited for Validation, if not work for you, better mark the actual solution for your jQuery question as answered and you open a second post for a second question (validation), as per @stackoverflow rules... 1 post one question ;)